# multiple versions of ant detected in path for junit

Tags: java, apache, intellij-idea, junit, ant

I'm running an integration test through an ant target and I'm getting the following error

```
WARNING: multiple versions of ant detected in path for junit 
     jar:file:/C:/Apps/apache-ant-1.8.4/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.class
 and jar:file:/c:/Oracle/Weblogic12.1.2/oracle_common/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.1/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.class
```

I've tried setting `fork="false"` and `includeantruntime="false"` but neither worked. Is there any way I can set the ant version in my xml? I need it to run on the latest version which I have installed and is the default version in IntelliJ, but it decides to use an older version I have installed which doesn't support the `methods` attribute which I am using to run a specific method within a test suite. Otherwise it runs every test in the class, which I don't want.

Comment: How's your classpath getting set up? Can you reorder it?

Comment: @dcsohl Under the ant targets' Build Properties>Additional Classpath I have ant 1.8.4 and then ant 1.9.4, both should work, yet my test is using ant 1.7.1, which I have installed but not specified in the classpath, to run.

Comment: Anything else in the classpath? You may have noticed that ant 1.7.1 is coming from Weblogic; can you reorder Weblogic relative to the other ant installations?